# To establish a relation between the given topologies on R.

Tags: general-topology

Let $T_1$ be the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$,
$T_2$ the $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$, where
$K=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $K$-topology is nothing more than the topology generated by basis elements of form $(a,b) \setminus K$. Let $T_3 = \{(-\infty,a) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Then establish the relation between them.

I know that the discrete topology is strictly finer than any other topology on $X$. Also $K$-topology is strictly finer than standard topology. What about other two topologies here. Are they comparable?

Comment: Note that the $K$-topology basis also contains regular open sets $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

The $K-$topology $\mathcal{T}_2$ is strictly finer than that of the usual topology $\mathcal{T}_1$.

And the usual topology $\mathcal{T}_1$ is strictly finer that of the topology $\mathcal{T}_3$.